# Initiate remote execution from mobile application and return results back

Tags: iphone, ios, rpc, xml-rpc

I am trying to modify a iPhone app in order to improve its performance. The original app has intensive computation so it expends much battery power. I am trying to make some parts of the app executed remotely: suspend local procedure, execute methods/threads on server, and return results back to phone.

I see some useful tools that may help, such as [XML-RPC](https://github.com/corristo/xmlrpc), [NSStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188-SW1), NSTask, and Apple's Web Services Core. But I am not sure which is the best practice.

Hope I have explained well enough. I am not very familiar with these frameworks, so I hope someone can explain a little bit and give me some suggestions about my goal.

Comment: How long will the processing take on the server? Is there a single result, or lots of updates to the response data? What about the amount of data sent, when its sent and the speed of the network?

Comment: @Wain Thanks for your reply. The time duration of processing on the server may vary, but generally, suppose the network is stable and fast, the task is simple, no multiple updates back and forth, the amount of data sent is small. Let's consider the basic situation here for now.